# Как получить объект с form (spring + thymeleaf)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю неправильно. При запуске программы и ввода данных в форму, в debug значения имени и пароля пустые(фото ниже).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role" , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    Getters and Setters ...

}
```

///

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(Model model){
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user",user);
        return "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String registerUser(User user, Map<String, Object> model){

        user.setActive(true);
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.USER));
        //userRepository.save(user);

        return "redirect:/login";
    }

}
```

///

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form th:action="@{/registration}" th:object="${user}" method="post" >
    <div><label>User name : <input type="text" th:name="*{name}" /></label></div>
    <div><label>User password : <input type="password" th:name="*{password}" /></label></div>
    <div><button type="submit">Create</button></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: debug]

Comment: Ну как минимум перед `User user` надо поставить `@ModelAttribute`

Comment: Добавил @ModelAttributte и в input значение value=''',  все также

Comment: Попробуйте добавить обеим полям в html значения value="". Также th:name="*{...}" возможно должны быть th:name="${...}"

Comment: не получается все также

Comment: @ResponseBody аннотацию попробуйте еще для контроллера

Comment: не получается все также

Comment: Поменяйте `th:name` на `th:field`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PostMapping("/registration")
    public String registerUser(@RequestParam
User user, Map model){

```
    user.setActive(true);
    user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.USER));
    //userRepository.save(user);

    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

}